# Azure SQL Database DTU percentage Reach 100% on particular function

Tags: c#, azure, query-optimization, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2014

My scenario is I have a button name(**`publish`**) at admin side use for publish agreement and after publish it visible to user-side. Recently I saw when I publish agreement 
**DTU** percent reach almost **100%** and I tested rest of all functionality **DTU** not goes upto **5%**.

My database size is **250mb** I upgraded the `DTU` to a higher tier(from **B1** to **B2**,**S1**,**S2**,**S3**) but when publish agreement it reach **100%**

[image]

*process took (3 minute maximum) when publish a large agreement*

I checked the Query that taking long time also not complicated

```
(@EntityKeyValue1 bigint)SELECT 
[Extent1].[Revision] AS [Revision], 
[Extent1].[ClauseVersionId] AS [ClauseVersionId], 
[Extent1].[SourceClauseVersionId] AS [SourceClauseVersionId], 
[Extent1].[DisplayHeader] AS [DisplayHeader], 
[Extent1].[Body] AS [Body], 
[Extent1].[EndUserGuidanceNote] AS [EndUserGuidanceNote], 
[Extent1].[DocumentParty_DocumentPartyId] AS [DocumentParty_DocumentPartyId], 
[Extent1].[PublishedClause_ClauseId] AS [PublishedClause_ClauseId]
FROM [dbo].[PublishedClauseVersion] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[PublishedClause_ClauseId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[PublishedClause_ClauseId] = @EntityKeyValue1)
```

I saw many answer and article but I didn't get any proper solution for this issue.

Comment: Is `PublishedClauseVersion` a view or a table? Are there any calculated fields in there? Even when this table would make up the entire 250mb and there would not be any indexing, it still shouldn't take 3 minutes to run through all of it. Are you sure it is the query that takes this long? (Looks like entity framework code, could it be your fetcher is doing other (complicated) stuff?)

Comment: Also, the usual tips: try an `UPDATE STATISTICS` on the table and have an index on `PublishedClause_ClauseId`. From some of the linked articles you might be 'I/O/Transaction Bound'...

Comment: @deroby  `PublishedClauseVersion` is a table and 3 minutes is maximum time  taken by code(when publish a big size agreement) I check this in network tab of browser. In azure I have applied `Index` and also run `UPDATE STATISTICS` on all tables.but still getting same Issue

Comment: @deroby yes query is genrated by entity framework code

Comment: if you have enabled peformance insight,can you paste output of that

Comment: also try posting schema of table involved along with execution plna

Comment: @TheGameiswar I saw this from performance insight(Long running query)  and posting schema of table involved along with execution plan? I did't understand its mean

Comment: How long does this query take to run if you run it from your dev box? And does it cause the same dtu spike?

Comment: @ZainRizvi I did't understand what you mean by **dev box** if its mean SSMS then I run this query on SSMS and it took less than 1 second and DTU not spike.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the 2 sides of the comparison matches , Meaning the PublishedClause_ClauseId is also BigInt Data type as the parameter you are using "@EntityKeyValue1" , Mismatching them cause query optimizer to either scan or not use indexes, Match them then redeploy